# at second remove

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does ***"at second remove"*** mean ***"of secondary importance and not as evident as other elements"***?

There is something deeply moving about such an encounter with nature, even if it is at second remove.

Answer (score 2):

No, it means something closer to "third hand".

Imagine you are watching a videotape of a cheetah chasing a gazelle, taken through a telephoto lens.  Then you might say, "There is something deeply moving about such an encounter with nature, even if it is at second remove."

Seeing the event through the telephoto lens is "one remove", that is one step "removed" (away) from the action; seeing the tape instead of watching it live is the second.